# Why PIL.ImageChops.difference and np.array difference have different results?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Why PIL.ImageChops.difference and np.array absolute difference have different results? Pillow document says ImageChops.difference acts just like absolute difference(https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html).

```
tamp_image = Image.open(tamp_file_path).convert("RGB")
orig_image = Image.open(orig_file_path).convert("RGB")
diff = ImageChops.difference(orig_image, tamp_image)
diff.show() #1
Image.fromarray(abs(np.array(tamp_image)-np.array(orig_image))).show() #2
```

results(top:#1, bottom:#2):

[image: PIL.Chops.difference]
[image: np.array difference]

Interestingly, if I convert `diff` to np.array and then Image object again, it shows like #1.

Comment: The components of the arrays are most likely unsigned 8-bit integers, so subtracting a larger value from a smaller value will cause a wrap-around.  Applying `abs()` to the result does absolutely nothing, there are no negative values possible in an unsigned type.  `ImageChops.difference()` is apparently using a larger, signed type for its intermediate result to avoid this problem (notionally at least, there may be some clever trick to do the operation entirely with 8-bit values).

Comment: Take a look at the result of, say, `np.array([1, 127, 255], dtype=np.uint8) - np.array([255, 128, 1], dtype=np.uint8)`, and you'll see what might go wrong.

Comment: Can you post your original images, so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The solution is quite simple, the converted numpy arrays have the datatype `uint8`. By subtracting large values, the bits will flip entirely, and you get some weird looking result.

So the solution is to convert the images to a datatype with an appropriate range, like `int8`.

```py
img1 = np.array(tamp_image, dtype='int8')
img2 = np.array(orig_image, dtype='int8')
diff = np.abs(img1 - img2)
Image.fromarray(np.array(diff, dtype='uint8')).show()
```